# How loop a sound seamlessly in Firemonkey (FMX)?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, firemonkey

How do you loop a sound seamlessly using the TMediaPlayer in Firemonkey (using XE6, C++ Builder)?

What I am doing so far is using a TTimer which checks

```cpp
if (MediaPlayer->CurrentTime >= MediaPlayer->Media->Duration)
{
  MediaPlayer->CurrentTime = 0;
  MediaPlayer->Play ();
}
```

but this doesn't create a seamless loop, even when the TTimer's Interval is set to 1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this component but assume, in Windows, it is a wrapper around DirectShow. That means you will never be able to get (frame) seamless playback because of the overhead of starting/stopping the graph. If you can live with a small hiccup, you probably get the best results (and certainly better code) if there is something like an OnLastFrame() event, in which you can reset the frame counter to the first frame (or CurrentTime to zero).

Comment: There are no accessible events with the XE6 Firemonkey TMediaPlayer component. What I'm doing currently has a small hiccup, my guess is similar to what you described.